# How to subset each column of a large matrix and combine this colnums (by colnum number) to generate e new matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, concatenation, subset, large-data

I have 8 matrices with 1000 colunms each (named V1 : V1000)

I need to combine each colunm of each matrix (all V1 of all matrices in one new matrix, all V2 of all matrices in other matrix tcc...) in a new matrix.

How could I do that in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code that you have tried so far? Thank you! :)

Comment: How are your matrices stored? What are their names?